# how to know from javascript loading in page or not

Tags: javascript, html

I have to javaScript files named as Js1, Js2. I would like to know from the Js2, is the Js1 is loaded on html page or not. Please share an example . Thank you.

Comment: How you are loading these files synchrounously or asynchronously?

Comment: Variable in the global scope are accessible anywhere, you can check for any global variable exists or not which is defined in a different JS file.

Comment: `script` tag has an onload event

Comment: @Prakash :- Is there any other way can achieve this instead of using global variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the beginning of your **js1** add this code:

```
var js1Loaded=true; //if your js1 is not wrapped in a function scope
window.js1Loaded=true //if your js1 is wrapped in a function scope
```

and in your **js2** check the condition with this code:

```
if(js1Loaded){ //or window.js1Loaded
    //js1 is loaded
}
```

**UPDATE**
another way to achieve this is using `DOMContentLoaded` event:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    //all the scripts are loaded
    //write your js2 code here
});
```

**Building on the comment**

> when do i need to write window.js1Loaded=true ? is this statement is end of the javascript ?

you need to write `window.js1Loaded=true` inside your js1 file (at the beginning or the end, actually doesn't matter).

> if i create boolean value in Js1, can able to access sample variable in Js2 alos ?

as I mentioned before if your js files are **not** wrapped in a function scope then yes you can simply write `var js1Loaded=true;` and access it from all the js files that loads after js1.

by function scope I mean this:

```
(function(){
    //your code here
}());
```

if your code is inside a function scope then you have to define your `js1Loaded` variable globally using `window.js1Loaded=true;`

**Quick Example**

**html**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        //some html elements here
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Script/js1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Script/js2.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**js1**

```
var js1Loaded=true;
//some js code here
```

**js2**

```
//some js code here
if(js1Loaded){
    alert('js1 is loaded');
}
```

but at the end I would really suggest that you use `DOMContentLoaded` event, it is more efficient!

Comment: Thanks Amin. Any other ways apart from Global variable?

Comment: Js1 has boolean value - var js1Loaded; when do i need to write window.js1Loaded=true ? is this statement is end of the javascript ? if i create boolean value in Js1, can able to access sample variable in Js2 alos ? Please explain. Thank you.

Comment: check out the examples

Comment: Awesome..This is really help me to understand, how it works.  Thank you Amin.